# cant write to firestore database before firebase authentication angular app

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing an angular app. I have two services (auth service) and (registration service). My registration service writes user data such as name and email to firestore, while my auth service (takes email and password from registration) creates a user account after my registration service  has written user data to firestore. This should be a relatively simple process. The problem is, my authservice manages to create a user account but my registration service does not write to the database. When I comment the call to the auth service, registration service manages to write to the database.

Auth service

```
this.afs.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,user.pass)
```

Registration Service

```
this.afs.collection('path').add({
  firstName: rUser.firstName,
  lastName: rUser.lastName,
  email: rUser.email
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error)
})
```

Now both services clearly work but registration service doesnt work when auth service is called.

I have searched everywhere but no solutions.

Here is my call to both services

```
this.rSERVICE.saving(registeredUser);
this.authService.signUpUser(registeredUser);
```

Comment: I think your authService.signUpUser should be called after rService.saving call finished successfully. One way to do is make your saving function returns a promise and put your singUpUser inside .then() block. If you still need an example, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you. That worked! but instead of a .then, I added an await rService.saving which ran after saving to the database.

Comment: Pleased to know about that. Await is fine but also you should make sure your registration is successful and handling error. Do you want I write up an answer that you can accept as the solution works?

Comment: Yes. Your solution is perfect! Thank you

Comment: If you think so, click on the solution and accept it as a correct answer is a way to acknowledge and help others who may have the same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because registration is an `async` task, make sure that this task is successfully completed before calling signup task.

One way to implement is making `saving` function return a `promise` and call `signUpUser` inside its `.then()` block. Something like this:

`registration.service`

```
// saving function return a promise
  saving(user: User): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(
        (resolve) => {
            this.afs.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.pass)
                .then(() => { resolve(true); })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.log(error);
                  throw new Error("Some error message here...");
                })})
  }
```

Consuming the services

```
this.rSERVICE.saving(registeredUser)
    .then(() => { this.authService.signUpUser(registeredUser); })
    .catch(error => { console.log(error); });
```